# WEBPACK build script breaking without a change

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I had set up a simple WEBPACK build script which was working fine till last night, now without any changes I am getting the following error and the server is not ready to start.

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:1000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1510:7)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:72:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rms-css-remidiation@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open --mode development`
npm ERR! Exit status
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the rms-css-remidiation@1.0.0 start script.
```

Below is my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
"build": "webpack -p"
},
```

Comment: The address `127.0.0.1:1000` is already in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says the address `127.0.0.1:1000` is already in use